# Prometheus/Grafana- how to generate data points for all pods?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I've deployed Prometheus and Grafana via helm by issuing the following command.

```
helm install --name prom --namespace monitoring  stable/Prometheus-operator
```

I've managed to use kubectl to port forward to grafana, and I can view the interface just fine.

However, most of my pods are not generating any data points. I've tried re-deploying the workloads as I figured maybe that was necessary for Prometheus to start picking up the metrics. I can select the pods in the workloads in Grafana drop-down menus so they are being detected, but they are not generating any data points or populating the graphs.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try opening `/targets` tab in prometheus ui (Status->Targets menu) and see if all of your kubelet targets are up.

Comment: Hello, I've just checked and the workload that I have added the annotation prometheus.io/scrape: 'true' to is not displayed. Is there any other steps I'm missing?

Comment: @nmh did you manage to resolve it? what was the issue?